# SQL Server Mirroring and automatic failover - why don't all DBs failover to the mirror?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, failover, mirroring

On SQL Server 2008 R2, I'm mirroring 20 databases on my SharePoint SQL Server with a witness, high-safety.  All mirrored DBs have the default mirroring_connection_timeout = 10.  And, occasionally, a handful of DBs will failover to the mirror (not more than once a month).  Today, it was 3 DBs and the only abnormality I noticed was some highish CPU at the time of failover.

I assume that the 10 second timeout for receiving a PING has been exceeded and failover occurs.  What I don't understand is why, if all DBs have the same timeout they don't all failover when this happens?

Comment: Can you have a look at errorlog and see what caused CPU usage to spike. May be some extensive operation like CHECKDB was running. Please also check errorlog of partner server.

Comment: I rarely find anything of use in the event log or SQL log associated with these failovers.  This was no exception.  No smoking gun so far.

I was more curious as to why just 3 of the 20 were affected.

Comment: If you plan to use high-safety mode with automatic failover, the normal load on each failover partner should be less than 50 percent of the CPU. If your work load overloads the CPU, a failover partner might be unable to ping the other server instances in the mirroring session. This causes a unnecessary failover. If you cannot keep the CPU usage under 50 percent, we recommend that you use either high-safety mode without automatic failover or high-performance mode. Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms366349.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that there is a separate ping for each database, not one for all. So some are successful and some fail. If you need all of the databases to fail over, I outlined a process (using service broker and event notifications) to detect a failover and make sure all mirrored databases fail over in my book [Pro SQL Server 2008 Mirroring](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430224231).

A lot of this information is also located on my blog here [Database Mirroring Automation](http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/databasemirroringautomation) and here: [How do I automatically respond to mirrored database failovers?](http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/howdoiautomaticallyrespondtomirroreddatabasefailovers)